# on_message returns to if message while inside on bot.command

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

First post and I'm trying to upgrade my Discord Bot!

At the moment the Bot is able to execute the !decklist fine, but when I occur in the if not message.attachments and I try to execute the !boh command, the bot responds with the if clause and also execute the !boh command.

Posting the code down below, many thanks for the help!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from io import BytesIO

TOKEN = 'disc_token'

def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    intents.members = True
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intents)
    
    #ON_READY
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        #SERVER = bot.get_guild(int(1156534000890953748))
        bot_name = await bot.fetch_user(int(1155959555876991098))
        await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'{bot_name}si è connesso a Discord')

    #SENDS USER EMBED TO RESPOND WITH IMAGE.
    @bot.command()
    async def decklist (ctx):
        """Riceve l'immagine della Decklist e la invia per la conferma"""
        embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_magenta(),
        title = ("Dreamborn"),
        url = ("https://dreamborn.ink/")
        )
        embed.set_image(url="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKCp5PneGn0VgoP-Hncj4AxiN-Ql2tqaKd6w&usqp=CAU")
        await ctx.send(f"Mandami l'immagine della Decklist esportata da **Dreamborn!**", ephemeral=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        @bot.event
        async def on_message(message):
            await bot.process_commands(message)
            if message.author == bot.user:
                return
            if message.author.bot:
                return
            if not message.attachments:
                #ignore (message=bot.command())
                await message.author.send('Ciao! La tua lista non è **idonea**.\nMandami una **immagine!**')
                pass
            image_file = message.attachments[0]
            image_bytes = await image_file.read()
            liste = bot.get_channel(int(1156534533907288064))
            istruzioni = bot.get_channel(int(1156626680794845234))
            await liste.send('**' + message.author.display_name + '**')
            await liste.send(file=discord.File(fp=BytesIO(image_bytes), filename=image_file.filename))
            await message.author.send('Oki doki, Decklist inviata! \nMetti la reazione al messaggio su' + istruzioni.mention + 'per essere Confermato! \nSe invece avevi già messo la reazione a Confermati, ignora!')
            await bot.process_commands(message)

    #REPLY WITH "HELLO"
    @bot.command()
    async def boh(ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"ciao!")

   bot.run(TOKEN)
run()
```

[problem view from discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIywn.png)

I'm just wondering how can I "exit" properly from the !decklist command in order to not fall again in the if clause in case I'm using other commands.

Comment: After you define `on_message()` in `decklist()`, that function will be executed for all future messages.

Comment: Ok, I got it! 

But I want the `decklist()` to go through the `if not message.attachments:` after the user used the `!decklist` command and, for example, typed the decklist instead of posting an actual image! So the `on_message` is not a correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, just replacing the `on_message` with `message = await bot.wait_for('message')`!

Full code in case you need! You can close this topic!

```
`import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from io import BytesIO

TOKEN = 'disc.token'

def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    intents.members = True
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents = intents)
    
    #ON_READY
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        bot_name = await bot.fetch_user(int(bot_id))
        await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'{bot_name}si è connesso a Discord')

    #SENDS USER EMBED TO RESPOND WITH IMAGE.
    @bot.command()
    async def decklist (ctx):
        """Riceve l'immagine della Decklist e la invia per la conferma"""
        embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.dark_magenta(),
        title = ("Dreamborn"),
        url = ("https://dreamborn.ink/")
        )
        embed.set_image(url="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKCp5PneGn0VgoP-Hncj4AxiN-Ql2tqaKd6w&usqp=CAU")
        await ctx.send(f"Mandami l'immagine della Decklist esportata da **Dreamborn!**", ephemeral=True)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        #WAITS FOR USER INTERACTIONS, IF ATTACHMENTS IS TRUE, POSTS THE ATTACHMENT INTO A DEDICATED CHANNEL
        message = await bot.wait_for('message')
        if message.author == bot.user:
                return
        if message.author.bot:
                return
        if not message.attachments:
                #ignore (message=bot.command())
            await message.author.send('Ciao! La tua lista non è **idonea**.\nMandami una **immagine!**')
            message = await bot.wait_for('message')
            pass
        image_file = message.attachments[0]
        image_bytes = await image_file.read()
        liste = bot.get_channel(int(1156534533907288064))
        istruzioni = bot.get_channel(int(1156626680794845234))
        await liste.send('**' + message.author.display_name + '**')
        await liste.send(file=discord.File(fp=BytesIO(image_bytes), filename=image_file.filename))
        await message.author.send('Oki doki, Decklist inviata! \nMetti la reazione al messaggio su' + istruzioni.mention + 'per essere Confermato! \nSe invece avevi già messo la reazione a Confermati, ignora!')

    bot.run(TOKEN)
run()`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).